# Json to PHP Table

Tags: symfony

```
$file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/myFile.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file("$file");
$json = json_encode($xml);
```

Here's my json code:

```
{
    "Commands1": [{
        "Name": "XLS1",
        "Activated": "true",
        "values": [{
            "Name": "Cmd",
            "default": "false"
        }, {
            "Name": "Ls",
            "default": "false"
        }, {
            "Name": "rmdir",
            "default": "false"
        }],
        "Commands2": [{
            "Name": "SKA1",
            "Activated": "true",
            "values": [{
                "Name": "Cp",
                "default": "false"
            }, {
                "Name": "Tcpdump",
                "default": "false"
            }, {
                "Name": "rmdir",
                "default": "false"
            }]

        }]
    }]
}
```

In my controller I open a XML file, and I'd like to know if it's possible to show its content in a table ? If so can someone give me a simple example ?

The result should be like

Name      |   Values

xls1 | cmd, ls,rmdir

SKA1 | cp, tcpdump,rmdir

Comment: Can you please post your Json String ?

Comment: why you want to have it in  json format ?

Comment: It is already in Json I'd like to show the json in a html table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it certainly is possible. You need to first decode it into an array.

```
$s = json_decode($json,true);
```

Then, comes the `foreach()` loop. You will have to consider each and every key-value pair and then iterate that loop to print your result. 
**PS:** Apparently, I found a mistake in your Json String. Your Commands2 is becoming a subset of Commands1. Here is your correct Json.

```
{
"Commands1": [
{
  "Name": "XLS1",
  "Activated": "true",
  "values": [
    {
      "Name": "Cmd",
      "default": "false"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Ls",
      "default": "false"
    },
    {
      "Name": "rmdir",
      "default": "false"
    }
  ]
}
],
"Commands2": [
{
  "Name": "SKA1",
  "Activated": "true",
  "values": [
    {
      "Name": "Cp",
      "default": "false"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Tcpdump",
      "default": "false"
    },
    {
      "Name": "rmdir",
      "default": "false"
    }
  ]
  }
  ]
}
```

And, Here is a reference, You can check How will your table look like when from JSON.http://json2table.com/ 
Now, Regarding your table, No one is gonna write the code for you on stack. So, I suggest go Baby steps if you wanna learn it. Here is a reference for you http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp

Answer (score 2):

The value of the JSON file decode it into a Associative Array and pass it to the view. From there act like you would acct with a normal AssocArray. 
In controller:

```
$assoc_array_results = json_decode($json_file_result);

return $this->render('view.html.twig', array('results' => $assoc_array_results));
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer, but that's exactly my question, I can't get the array in my twig view but i don't know how to show it in a table format instead of string... i'm a beginner

Comment: in twig: 
{% for result in results %}
  <td>{{ result['Name'] }}</td> <td> {{ result['Activated'] }} </td>  // And so on
{% endfor %}
Just loop throw the array

Comment: the response of the controller